# How do I prove that the following argument is valid for any finite universe of discourse?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'd like to prove that the following argument is valid for any finite universe of discourse.

$$
\begin{aligned}
1.\ & ( \exists x )(\exists y) Gxy \\
2.\ &(x) \lnot Gxx \\ 
3.\ &(x)(y)(z)[(Gxy \land Gyz) \to Gxz] \\
\therefore 4.\ &(\exists x)(\exists y)[Gxy \land \lnot (\exists z)Gzx] \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The argument is not quantificationaly valid, because there are interpretations on which 1-3 are true, but 4 is false.

For instance:

UD: Set of positive integers
Gxy: x is greater than y

Which gives us,

1. Some positive integer is greater than another positive integer
2. No positive integer is greater than itself.
3. For all positive integers x, y, and z, if x is greater than y and y is greater than z, then x is greater than z.

Therefore,

4. For some positive integer x and some positive integer y, x is greater than y and there is no positive integer z such that z is greater than x—some integer is the greatest positive integer.

1-3 are clearly true while 4 is false, so the argument is invalid on this interpretation.

If we change the interpretation so that Gxy = x is less than y, believe the argument is valid on this new interpretation.

Of course, it is also valid for *some* interpretations where the UD is finite.

For example:

UD: {Jack, Jill, Susan}
Gxy: x is taller than y

Or:

UD: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Gxy: x is greater than y

Intuitively, it seems to me that this argument will be valid for *all* interpretations where the UD is finite, but how do I demonstrate this mathematically?

Comment: **Note:** The domain and relation (G) for your examples form a *strict partially ordered set* with a *minimum* element.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamKemp. I'll have to spend some time researching strict partially ordered sets.

Answer (score 2):

Note that premises 2 and 3 would be true if and only if $G$ is irreflexive and transitive. That means that $G$ has to be a strict partial order.

Examples of partial orders would be just the kinds of things you indicate: greater than or smaller than on the integers, taller than on people, etc. However, note that those are all all *total* orders: for any two different objects, either one will be 'greater than' the other, or vice versa. This need not be true for a *partial* order. For example, the (strict) subset relationship on sets is a (strict) partial order: it is transitive and irreflexive ... but it is not always the case that for any two different sets, one is the subset of the other.

However, if you have a partial order, you can still 'line up' all the objects in such a way that any 'greater than' relation that does hold goes from 'left' to right'.  Or, if you want to think about this graphically: if the objects are nodes, and any relationship $G$ between $a$ and $b$ is an arrow from node $a$ to $b$, then there are no directional cycles ... for if there would be, then the transitive closure would force there to be an arrow from an object to itself, and it would no longer be irreflexive. In fact, having lined up all objects this way, you could even add an arrow between any two objects from left to right (this would be the equivalent of extending the partial order into a linear order).

OK, so whether our order is total or merely partial, by transitivity and irreflexivity, it must be true that we can line up all objects from 'left' to 'right' so that any relationship (arrow) goes from left to right.  However, given that there are only a finite number of objects, and given that by premise $1$ there is at least one relationship (arrow), it must be true that there is a left-most element that still has an outgoing arrow, but no incoming arrow. But given that element, the conclusion is true. This argument works for *any* finite domain and interpretation of $G$, and hence the conclusion does follow from the premises for any finite domain.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention strict partial order. I've considered a graphic illustration with points and arrows in my own thinking about the argument. My concern is that the illustration shows that the argument is valid on one more interpretation, but not that it is valid for every finite UD. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @Chris OK, how about this: *any* interpretarion that makes 2 and 3 true has to be an order, meaning that for *any* such interpretation, we can line up its objects. Also, we know from 1 that there is at least one arrow. Now let's do a proof by contradiction. if the conclusion is not true, then that means that the node with the outgoing arrow should have an incoming arrow. And, given the ordering, that incomong arrow should come from an object/node that is to the left of it. But then *that* object should have an incoming arrow, etc.etc. In other words, the domain would have to be infinite.

Comment: Again very helpful. Just to clarify are partially ordered sets *orders*? Or do they merely contain *orders*? In other words, would it be accurate to say any interpretation which makes 2 and 3 true the UD *is* an order or that it must *contain* an order? For example, an interpretation where the UD is a set of 30 coins and Gxy = x is stacked on top of y. Premise 1 requires there to be at least one stack and, since the UD is finite, there must be a first and last element for each stack/order.

Comment: Could I articulate a proof as follows? 
Since G is both irreflexive and transitive, any element of the UD under the extension of G must be a part of a strictly ordered set. Premise one states that there are at least two elements under the extension of G, so there must be at least one strictly ordered set in UD. Finally, every finite strictly ordered set has both a first and last member, so the statement $$(\exists x)(\exists y)[Gxy \land \lnot (\exists z)Gzx]$$ must be true for all finite interpretations of the argument.

Comment: @Chris Every partial order can be extended to a total order, sure, that works!